# Dev console encoding error in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, character-encoding, qt5

When there's any errors in my project it looks like that:

[image]

How to fix that? I mean encoding, not errors.

Comment: Why do you think it is a qt issue rather than QtCreator setting? Can you reproduce this on the command line?

Comment: Yes, i made a mistake. I meant Qt Creator. Didn't find any options that should affect on encoding. Tried to switch language, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using QtCreator 3.0? Which operating system are you running on? Can you reproduce the issue on the command line?

Comment: QtCreator v3.0.0, Windows 7. Didn't understant, what you mean by "reproduce the issue". Should i launch some qt code via command line or it's enought to run standart commands?

Comment: Just run your code through the cmd.exe or visual studio prompt.

Comment: It's some kind another problem. Just started Qt.Can you give me a link how to do it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43869/discussion-between-sugar-and-laszlo-papp)

Comment: Can you try an English Windows by any chance to see if it is related to your localized Windows? I am not a guru myself... just scanning in the dark. :)

Comment: This is a [bug of Qt Creator](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-316). Unfortunately still not solved…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Visual Studio compiler with Qt Creator, message from compiler will be in DOS (866)  encoding. Need set correct encoding Windows CP1251. I use special version jom.exe from here.

Version x86: [jom.exe x86](http://borus.org/jom/x86/jom.exe)

Version x64: [jom.exe x64](http://borus.org/jom/x64/jom.exe)

Copy utility in qt/bin. Then Tools->Options and find options "use jom instead nmake". [Source](http://borus.org/qtcreator_kodirovka.php).

Answer (score 3):

- Go to Tools -> Options -> Kits.
- Select the used kit.
- Select the "Force MSVC UTF-8 Compiler Output" checkbox.

Comment: Great! It worked for me. Text is readable now. I think it's better than using custom tools (as proposed in accepted answer), or hardcoding encoding in pro file (others may use different encoding in their system)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to amend the problem by editing .pro file only. The console codepage is inherited when the console is inherited. So it's sufficient to change the console codepage for the make command. And that can be done with (somewhat) advanced qmake.

Insert this into your .pro file. It works for me.

```
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += before_build makefilehook

makefilehook.target = $(MAKEFILE)
makefilehook.depends = .beforebuild

PRE_TARGETDEPS += .beforebuild


before_build.target = .beforebuild
before_build.depends = FORCE
before_build.commands = chcp 1251
```

If you prefer Russian language read [this post](http://blog.mgsxx.com/?p=2979) on my blog.

Answer (score -1):

Better solution is here, cause not only jom can output such messages but link, nmake, copy, etc:
http://codedchaos.blogspot.com/2012/09/qt-creator-windows.html

Need to use command:

> chcp scode_page

Simple sample:

> chcp 1251

To permanently change code page registry `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` could be used. To run Qt Creator you may create bat file with following:

```
@echo off
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /t reg_expand_sz /d "chcp 1251 1>nul" /f
C:\Qt\qtcreator-3.6.0\bin\qtcreator.exe
reg delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /f
```